# MVC Route Error Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to catch the latest unhandled error application and redirect it to error page whenever error has occurred. But I got error "No matching route found for RedirectToRoute." What's the problem with my code? Here's my implementation:

**Global.asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ErrorHandler",
        "{ErrorHandler}/{action}/{errMsg}",
       new {controller="ErrorHandler", action = "Index", errMsg = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

**Application_End**

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var strError = Server.GetLastError().Message;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strError)) return;
            Response.RedirectToRoute("ErrorHandler", new {controller="ErrorHandler", action = "Index", errMsg = strError });
            this.Context.ClearError();
        }
```

**ErrorHandler Controller**

```
public class ErrorHandlerController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index(string errMsg)
        {
            ViewBag.Exception = errMsg;
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**To Test the error handler on my Home Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //just intentionally added this code so that exception will occur
            int.Parse("test");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Updated**

typo "contoller". Thanks to drch. But still I got error "No matching route found for RedirectToRoute."

Comment: Just a wild guess but have you tried naming your route something different i.e. ErrorHandlerRoute ??

Comment: @dreza. I recently tried your suggestion unfortunately I still got "No matching route found for RedirectToRoute."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a problem with your route definitions.

The route you have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ErrorHandler",
    "{ErrorHandler}/{action}/{errMsg}",
   new {controller="ErrorHandler", action = "Index", errMsg = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

is VERY eager and will cause problems.  That's going to match any url that's `http://yoursite/anything/anything/*`.  Because your HomeController.Index is even being executed, it means that the routing was already matched with an even more greedy route (perhaps the default one?).

So there's 2 things -

1) you need to move your error handler route up higher.  MVC uses the first matching route it finds in the route table.

2) make your route less greedy, ie:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ErrorHandler",
    "ErrorHandler/{action}/{errMsg}",
   new {controller="ErrorHandler", action = "Index", errMsg = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! Now the error is gone! But there is another issue. I got another issue saying "Resource cannot be found". I noticed that the redirected URL goes like this "/ErrorHandler/Index/Input%20Blah blah blah". It should be "/ErrorHandler?errMsg=Blah blah blah"

Comment: I _think_ that if you remove "{errMsg}" so it's just "ErrorHandler/{action}" the message will end up as ?errMsg=blah

Comment: No i didn't remove the errMsg it's still the same  "ErrorHandler/{action}/{errMsg}"

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy it's now Okay. I just changed Response.RedirectToRoute("ErrorHandler", new { strErrMsg=errMsg });